# How to have an object in every Rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a new site in Rails, and in the footer of every page there is a newsletter sign-up form. (the form is part of the application.html.erb template) In the "index" action for the home page, I have `@email = EmailNewsletterMember.new` to provide an object for `form_for` to work with. I just now realized that in order to have this work, EVERY action for EVERY page will have to have this code. I know there has got to be a correct way to do this, can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter { @email = EmailNewsletterMember.new }
  ...
end
```

You could also potentially just throw `EmailNewsletterMember.new` directly into your `form_for` but only if there's nothing else you need to do with the object.

```
form_for(EmailNewsletterMember.new) do |f|
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that in a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`.